# Is it okay to use metal to house a thumbdrive?

Tags: grounding, usb-device

I have an opportunity to craft some novelty thumb drive housings. A number of these consist solely of the 4 contacts on plastic and the metal ground housing, similar to this (with out plastic cap)[image]

Can I fuse metal to the portion that does not fit into the port,
or do I need to insulate the ground housing from where the USB is handled?

*Source: Digikey.com*

Comment: The metal shield of a USB connector should always be grounded, so there won't be any safety concerns about touching it. Is that what you're asking about? (I'm aware of some frankly terrifying exceptions to this rule in some cheaply made stuff that isn't remotely to the USB spec where you can get mains voltage on a USB shield.... But that should never happen in anything sensibly made)

Comment: Metallic USB thumb drives do exist so this isn't anything new. My consern is, what if the PC requires to be connected to earthed/grounded mains socket, but is plugged into unearthed/ungeounded mains socket? I guess the extra metal sticking out does not make a huge difference in that case any more.